# My bean plants appear to have rust

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, beans

They're a variety called 'yard long' I think. Could somebody confirm or let me know what else it could be? What's the best way to treat them?

It has been a pretty wet spring. We're in zone 3/4.

Oops - here are the images: 
http://m.imgur.com/nqFAWkf
http://m.imgur.com/cO3kXF5

Comment: Please post pictures of the leaves and maybe the entire plant. Once we can see it, diagnosis should be a snap.

Comment: Totally intended to, then skipped that step. Oops. Images added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the spots are actually just soil on the leaves, or places where the dirt sat too long, and killed a small portion of leaf. The soil is probably from splashing off the ground during rain. The soil dissipates throughout a droplet, then settles in a layer where the droplet was after drying off. The dirt should come off easily with a light rinse with ambient purified water. Also, cleaning the leaf undersides usually has more effect toward increasing plant health, because lots more dirt gets splashed on there.

Real bean rust is easy to see, as it invariably develops a yellow patch around each infection. Here are some photos to compare against:

[image][image]

Your plants actually look fairly healthy, and if you keep a good eye on them and catch disease early, you should get a good crop.